# Delete group on ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

i have a big problem. I want to delete a group from a **ExpandableListView** and then "update list" with **notifyDataSetChange**.
I have this code:

```
db.deleteMarket(name); // remove group from database
expandableListDetail.remove(expandableListTitle.get(groupPos)); //remove from list
((BaseExpandableListAdapter) expandableListAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The system successfully removes the group from the database, but it still appears and I need to restart the application to update.
How can I update directly right after deletion?

Comment: It may be different adapter which you update?

Comment: it should be probably `expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: i tried with expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but android studio said "Cannot resolve method notifydatasetchange();